# How do i store api requested json data into an array

Tags: php, json

I have made a function which makes a API request. (functions.php) i have called this function to a file called (results.php) the function selects the ID from the search input takes lat and long from the database,
I want to be able to do a for each on the data returned. for every object store the lat and long into an array. Paste the json data into a json viewer to see it better. The whole thing works from the database connection to the output of data i just cant figure out how to store this json data into a variable and like i said put the lat and long of every object into an array

**FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
function locate($id, $connect) { //connect is coming from connection.php


 // Using prepared Statements means that SQL injection is not possible. Selects      ID from search input takes lat and long.

  if ($stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT Lat, Lng FROM List WHERE ID = ? LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error())) { 
  $stmt->bind_param('i', $id ); // Bind "$id" to parameter.
  $stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
  $stmt->store_result();
  $stmt->bind_result($lat, $lng); // get variables from result.
  $stmt->fetch();

  if($stmt->num_rows == 1) // If the id exists
  { 
    // Point to where you downloaded the phar
    include('httpful.phar');

    // Api request!
    $response = \Httpful\Request::get('https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat='.$lat.'&lng='.$lng)->send();
    echo $response;

  } 

  else
  {
     // No lat & long exists. 
     echo 'noUser';
     return false;
  }
```

}
}

**RESULTS.PHP**

```
$id=$_POST["hiddenField"]; //ID equals the hidden field post made from the   search university form
locate($id, $connect); //function from functions.PHP
```

**JSON DATA**

```
[{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.629543","street":{"id":1199924,"name":"On or near Parking Area"},"longitude":"-0.744038"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"1504b407304004387c9ad979acce910041bab568af1e833045a6deb157c621ae","id":45880896,"location_subtype":"","month":"2015-12"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.632071","street":{"id":1199912,"name":"On or near Bridge Street"},"longitude":"-0.756033"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"edc5f6be254e489548aad05aa5a92a3d1976fa668658940bb760aefb82788b0f","id":45882456,"location_subtype":"","month":"2015-12"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.629583","street":{"id":1200038,"name":"On or near Bushey Close"},"longitude":"-0.773352"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"65c9fe3cb702f5bf7c147700262595e15ce1827d7484271dedef06444789447c","id":45880856,"location_subtype":"","month":"2015-12"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.632071","street":{"id":1199912,"name":"On or near Bridge Street"},"longitude":"-0.756033"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"a604dbb1811a70e75709b01b492d19290a42fdaacaac1124f6c5b4a588b32d74","id":45882455,"location_subtype":"","month":"2015-12"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.628932","street":{"id":1200020,"name":"On or near Sabina
```

Answer (score 1):

[See `json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
//Input (json) string/array
$string = '[{"Foo":"bar","123":456}]';

//Convert to PHP array
$array = json_decode($string, true):

//Output to check
print_r($array);
```

The above will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Foo] => bar
            [123] => 456
        )
)
```

Comment: That makes sense yeah but I dont know where to put this code and my inputs arent manual they come from the API. Theres no for each